# widgetSelected() and different OS platform behaviors

Tags: java, linux, swt, listener

I have this Java code where I implement a `selectionListener`.
While it works great on Windows, surprisingly, it doesn't work on Linux (Debian 9.9, Cinnamon) and when I debug, the `println` code is never reached.
Any idea why it would work on one platform (Win?) but not on another (Linux) ?

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(container, SWT.TIME | SWT.MEDIUM | SWT.BORDER);
        FormToolkit tk =new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
        tk.adapt(dt, true, false);
        dt.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                           System.out.println("Event caught!");
}
```

Comment: If you are using a current version of SWT and the target environment is among the supported platforms, I suggest filing a bug. BTW the style is incorrect, only one of `SORT`, `MEDIUM`, or `LONG` is allowed (https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDateTime.html)

Comment: The code for SWT controls is completely different on each platform, so it is possible for problems to arise on a single platform. I don't see any obvious bug reports for this on Eclipse [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org)

Comment: Ok, I have created a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547489). Thanks

Comment: A note on your bug report - you are being asked to attach a complete [mcve] to the bug - something that can be run and shows the problem. The easier you make it to reproduce the problem the more likely you are to get progress.

Comment: I saw that and I thought that my snippet was enough but I guess I will have to provide a complete .java file/class so one doesn't have to write any additional code?

Comment: I have created a code ready to be used that reproduces the issue. I have updated my Eclipse bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per my bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547489), this issue is fixed in [Eclipse 2019-09](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-09)